# Sample for Arraybinding using C# Oracle managed data nuget and stored procedures

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am trying to use Arraybinding to load multiple rows into a table. The approach works for inline queries but not when done via Stored Procedure.

I am expecting that an exception is raised with inner Errors object populated with row numbers where it failed.

This is an example from Oracle site and it works perfectly fine for me. But as soon as i replace the inline query with a stored procedure, it fails with single error and doesn't contain any information for the row which failed.

https://docs.oracle.com/html/B14164_01/featOraCommand.htm#i1007888

```
/* Database Setup
drop table depttest;
create table depttest(deptno number(2));
*/
```

This is the program

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; 

class ArrayBindExceptionSample
{
  static void Main()
  {
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=oracle;";
con.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

// Start a transaction
OracleTransaction txn = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

try
{
  int[] myArrayDeptNo = new int[3] { 10, 200000, 30 };
  // int[] myArrayDeptNo = new int[3]{ 10,20,30};

  // Set the command text on an OracleCommand object
  cmd.CommandText = "insert into depttest(deptno) values (:deptno)";
  cmd.Connection = con;

  // Set the ArrayBindCount to indicate the number of values
  cmd.ArrayBindCount = 3;

  // Create a parameter for the array operations
  OracleParameter prm = new OracleParameter("deptno", OracleDbType.Int32);

  prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  prm.Value = myArrayDeptNo;

  // Add the parameter to the parameter collection
  cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

  // Execute the command
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (OracleException e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("OracleException {0} occured", e.Message);
  if (e.Number == 24381)
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Errors.Count; i++)
      Console.WriteLine("Array Bind Error {0} occured at Row Number {1}", 
        e.Errors[i].Message, e.Errors[i].ArrayBindIndex);

  txn.Commit();
}
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from depttest";

decimal rows = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Console.WriteLine("{0} row have been inserted", rows);
con.Close();
con.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Replace the code with stored procedure

```
cmd.CommandText = "SPName";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Stored Procedure

```
PROCEDURE trial (p_deptno             IN number)
   AS

   BEGIN
         insert into ses.depttest(deptno) values (P_deptno);
   END trial;
```

Comment: Similar issues from Oracle Support https://community.oracle.com/thread/235984 and 
 https://community.oracle.com/thread/268358

Comment: PROCEDURE trial (p_deptno             IN number,
                                    p_deptname            IN VARCHAR2)
   AS

   BEGIN
         insert into ses.depttest(deptno, deptname) values (P_deptno, P_deptname);
   END trial;

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31468018/1704458 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31387136/1704458

Comment: This is a different approach. OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray

Comment: 1. Post the error you get. 2. where you have `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` - change to `int cnt =  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` - do you get `cnt == 3` ?.

Comment: I am expecting the same results from both approaches a) using inline query b) using stored procedure. If there is any error while trying to insert 5 rows an Oracle Exception is returned with the Errors object with the row numbers which failed. With the stored procedure approach it just returns the first failure.

Comment: @T.S. i have included the entire program with the DDL to  create the  sample table

Comment: There are multiple approaches to do bulk uploads but i am looking at a specific approach as mentioned in the support article in the original post.

Comment: @T.S.Added the stored procedure code as well for reference to the original post.

Comment: There is no actual error that i am seeing, its just that i am not seeing the expected results which i shared.

Comment: your stored proc has 2 parameters but c# - 1. Have you added second parameter in code? And add `command.ArrayBindCount = myArrayDEptNo.Length;`  I feel, if there is no error and no data that could be issue. What if you for now remove one SP parameter and try to polish with single parameter?

Comment: Proc corrected to reflect single parameter.

Comment: i would suggest that you try to run it locally and check the results. Like i mentioned the feature is supposed to behave in a certain way and that works as per documentation when i use inline query but not when i use a stored procedure. the procedure is correct as it works for single row but not for multiple rows. I have shared all the components needed for it to be tested locally.

Comment: I have set the Arraybindcount =3 which is technically same as  myArrayDEptNo.Length.