# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core (Odp.Net Core) User Defined Type and Associative Array Type

Tags: asp.net-core, plsql, .net-core, user-defined-types, odp.net-managed

I want pass a user defined type or associative array with type to a store procedure in dotnet core with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core (Odp.Net Core). But I can't find any clear example.

Has Odp.net Core support User Defined Type or Associative Array Type, I don't know.

This is my type;

```
TYPE TYP_BC_RECORD is record (
      unique_id             depo.bc_stok_har.unique_id%type,
      transaction_hash      depo.bc_stok_har.transaction_hash%type,
      transaction_error     depo.bc_stok_har.transaction_error%type
 );
 TYPE TABLE_TYPE_BCRECORD IS TABLE OF TYP_BC_RECORD;
```

the store procedure paramater;

```
PROCEDURE P_SetResultBcHksRecordList(arBC_RECORD TABLE_TYPE_BCRECORD);
```

and dotnet core code;

```
OracleCommand OCommAPI = new 
OracleCommand("Depo.SPHKSBLOCKCHAIN.P_SetResultBcHksRecordList", conn);
OCommAPI.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


OracleParameter arBC_RECORD = new OracleParameter
{
  OracleDbType = ?,
  ParameterName = "arBC_RECORD ",
  //I don't know what I suppossed to write here. ?
  //RetUniqueID.Value = item;
  Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
};
CommAPI.Parameters.Add(arBC_RECORD);
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - no. ODP.NET did not support custom type. [See what was supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31468018/1704458) .

[image]

[Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/18.3/odpnt/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.html#GUID-E5D6E666-49EA-4A8D-822A-A190101C33D7)