# Pass Oracle User Defined Type Collection to Stored Procedure Using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

I'm trying to pass an oracle User Defined Type to a stored procedure as an input parameter using C# (Which is a collection), but each time I receive back an InvalidCastException saying "Column contains NULL data".

I have been followed a tutorial which shows the steps needed to achieve this.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1139474/ODP-NET-User-Defined-Type-Implementation

Each time, the code reaches

```
await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

And then throws the exception

```
    type ARTICLES_TYP is record(
      article_id number(6),
      article_name varchar(50),
      update_date date
    );
    
    type ARTICLES_LIST_TYP is table of ARTICLES_TYP;
    
    PROCEDURE MyProcedure (i_articles_list in ARTICLES_LIST_TYP);
```

```
    // A custom class mapping to an Oracle user defined type.
        // Provided all required implementations by ODP.NET developer guide to represent the Oracle UDT as custom type.
        // The custom class must implement IOracleCustomType and INullable interfaces.
        // Note: Any Oracle UDT name must be uppercase.
        public class Article : IOracleCustomType, INullable
        {
            // A private member indicating whether this object is null.
            private bool ObjectIsNull;
    
            // The OracleObjectMapping attribute is required to map .NET custom type member to Oracle object attribute.
            [OracleObjectMapping("ARTICLE_ID")]
            public int ArticleId { get; set; }
            [OracleObjectMapping("ARTICLE_NAME")]
            public string ArticleName { get; set; }
            [OracleObjectMapping("UPDATE_DATE")]
            public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    
            // Implementation of interface IOracleCustomType method FromCustomObject.
            // Set Oracle object attribute values from .NET custom type object.
            public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, object udt)
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, udt, "ARTICLE_ID", ArticleId);
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, udt, "ARTICLE_NAME", ArticleName);
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, udt, "UPDATE_DATE", UpdateDate);
            }
    
            // Implementation of interface IOracleCustomType method ToCustomObject.
            // Set .NET custom type object members from Oracle object attributes.
            public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, object udt)
            {
                ArticleId = (int)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, udt, "ARTICLE_ID");
                ArticleName = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, udt, "ARTICLE_NAME");
                UpdateDate = (DateTime)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, udt, "UPDATE_DATE");
            }
    
            // A property of interface INullable. Indicate whether the custom type object is null.
            public bool IsNull
            {
                get { return ObjectIsNull; }
            }
    
            // Static null property is required to return a null UDT.
            public static Article Null
            {
                get
                {
                    Article obj = new Article();
                    obj.ObjectIsNull = true;
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }
    
        // A custom type factory class is required to create an instance of a custom type representing an Oracle object type.
        // The custom type factory class must implement IOralceCustomTypeFactory class.
        // The OracleCustomTypeMapping attribute is required to indicate the Oracle UDT for this factory class.
        [OracleCustomTypeMapping("MYPACKAGE.ARTICLES_TYP")]
        public class ArticleFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory
        {
            // Implementation of interface IOracleCustomTypeFactory method CreateObject.
            // Return a new .NET custom type object representing an Oracle UDT object.
            public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
            {
                return new Article();
            }
        }


// A custom class mapping to an Oracle collection type.
    public class ArticleList : IOracleCustomType, INullable
    {
        // The OracleArrayMapping attribute is required to map .NET class member to Oracle collection type.
        [OracleArrayMapping()]
        public Article[] objArticles;

        // A private member indicating whether this object is null.
        private bool ObjectIsNull;

        // Implementation of interface IOracleCustomType method FromCustomObject.
        // Set Oracle collection value from .NET custom type member with OracleArrayMapping attribute.
        public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, object udt)
        {
            OracleUdt.SetValue(con, udt, 0, objArticles);
        }

        // Implementation of interface IOracleCustomType method ToCustomObject.
        // Set .NET custom type member with OracleArrayMapping attribute from Oracle collection value.
        public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, object udt)
        {
            objArticles = (Article[])OracleUdt.GetValue(con, udt, 0);
        }

        // A property of interface INullable. Indicate whether the custom type object is null.
        public bool IsNull
        {
            get { return ObjectIsNull; }
        }

        // Static null property is required to return a null UDT.
        public static ArticleList Null
        {
            get
            {
                ArticleList obj = new ArticleList();
                obj.ObjectIsNull = true;
                return obj;
            }
        }
    }

    // A custom type factory class is required to crate an instance of a custom type representing an Oracle collection type.
    // The custom type factory class must implement IOralceCustomTypeFactory and IOracleArrayTypeFactory class.
    // The OracleCustomTypeMapping attribute is required to indicate the Oracle UDT for this factory class.
    [OracleCustomTypeMapping("MYPACKAGE.ARTICLES_LIST_TYP")]
    public class ArticleListFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory, IOracleArrayTypeFactory
    {
        // Implementation of interface IOracleCustomTypeFactory method CreateObject.
        // Return a new .NET custom type object representing an Oracle UDT collection object.
        public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
        {
            return new ArticleList();
        }

        // Implementation of interface IOracleArrayTypeFactory method CreateArray to return a new array.
        public Array CreateArray(int numElems)
        {
            return new Article[numElems];
        }

        // Implementation of interface IOracleArrayTypeFactory method CreateStatusArray to return a new OracleUdtStatus array.
        public Array CreateStatusArray(int numElems)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Execution Code**

```
OracleParameter p = new();
            p.ParameterName = "i_articles_list";
            p.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Array;
            p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            ArticleList al = new ArticleList();
            Article[] articles = new Article[2]
            {
                new Article() { ArticleId = 2, ArticleName = "article two", UpdateDate = DateTime.Today },
                new Article() { ArticleId = 3, ArticleName = "article three", UpdateDate = DateTime.Today }
            };
            al.objArticles = articles;
            p.Value = al;
            p.UdtTypeName = "MYPACKAGE.ARTICLES_LIST_TYP";
            
            OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "MYPACKAGE.MyProcedure";
            command.Parameters.Add(p);

            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

[image: Thrown Invalid Cast Exception]

Does anyone have any idea why It keeps throwing this error?

Comment: I suggest to look here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31468018/1704458
You have `OracleDbType.Array` but you only have a single record.

Comment: The question you have suggested refers to a collection type of PLSQLAssociativeArray. Which is used for none User Defined Types.